# Repaint the map after updating a feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I update a feature in a vector layer using the following Python code:

```
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()     
layer = layers.get('my_vector20140614125509945')

fid = 1
attrs = { 0 : "hello", 1 : 100 }
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ fid : attrs })
```

The feature is updated but the map is not redrawn.  I am using catagorized style.  The value of 100 will be shown with a different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to tell the canvas to refresh.

```
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Comment: I tried to get the canvas by canvas = qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas() and call canvas.refresh() But the map is not repainted.  But after I clicked the map, it is repainted.

Comment: Thank you very much.  iface.mapCanvas().refresh() works.